# How to copy a entire directory which contains symlinks?

Tags: directory, copy, symlink, freebsd, cp

I want to copy a complete directory content from `/home/private_html/userx/` into the `/home/private_html/usery/`, the problem is that the directory `userx` contains few symlinks, and when using the `cp` it just skip them (skip occurs, if symlinks directs into a `file`, in case if it points into the directory, it just copy WHOLE directory instead...).

The command I was using looks following:

```
# cp -iprv /home/private_html/userx/ /home/private_html/usery/
```

Has anyone a solution to copy the directory "just as it is" into other place?

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD, `cp` doesn't have an `-r` option. It does have `-R`, which should do what you want:

```
 -R    If source_file designates a directory, cp copies the directory and
       the entire subtree connected at that point.  If the source_file
       ends in a /, the contents of the directory are copied rather than
       the directory itself.  This option also causes symbolic links to be
       copied, rather than indirected through, and for cp to create spe‐
       cial files rather than copying them as normal files.  Created
       directories have the same mode as the corresponding source direc‐
       tory, unmodified by the process' umask.
```

Answer (score 0):

Roland is right about the -R flag. You could also use a pair of tar-processes, which would make your command a little bit more system-independent:

```
tar -C /home/private_html/userx/ -cpf - . | tar -C /home/private_html/usery/ -epf -
```